# Eliminar filas de una matriz en función de elementos de una lista

Tags: python, lista, matriz

Como eliminar varias filas de una matriz comparando el primer elemento de cada fila con los elementos de la lista en python:

```
a= [181, 182, 185, 186]
m1= [[181 325 337]
     [182 326 338]
     [183, 327, 339]
     [184, 328, 340]]
```

Quedaría así:

```
[[183, 327, 339]
 [184, 328, 340]]

import numpy as np
for i in m1:
    for j in a:
        if np.array_equal(df[0,0],a[i]):
            print(df)
```

Comment: Revertí tu edición porque el código es esencial en la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una comprensión de listas que recorra tus filas y deje pasar solo a las que no tengan su primer elemento en el conjunto `a`. Es decir:

```
result = [fila for fila in m1 if fila[0] not in set(a)]
```

Lo que genera el resultado `[[183, 327, 339], [184, 328, 340]]`

**Nota**. Se podía omitir el uso del conjunto y poner simplemente `... not in a]`, pero el conjunto es más eficiente. Buscar si un elemento está o no está en una lista tarda más cuanto mayor sea la lista. En cambio en un conjunto tarda siempre lo mismo sin importar su tamaño. En este caso, en que la lista `a` es tan pequeña, la diferencia será inapreciable, pero está bien conocer el truco para otros casos mayores.

**Nota 2**. El formato que has dado a la pregunta me hace pensar que estás usando arrays numpy. La idea funciona también en este caso, con una ligera modificación para que el resultado sea también otro array numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a= [181, 182, 185, 186]
m1 = np.array([[181, 325, 337],
     [182, 326, 338],
     [183, 327, 339],
     [184, 328, 340]])
result = np.array([fila for fila in m1 if fila[0] not in set(a)])
```

Y el resultado es

```
array([[183, 327, 339],
       [184, 328, 340]])
```